# How to activate input box (fiddle provided) through browser scripting

Tags: javascript, scripting, client-side, web-console

How do I programmatically click on an input box to make it become activated. I'm doing scripting through Developer Tools. Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried .focus() and .click() properties like:

```
      document.getElementById("myText").focus();
```

fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/nep95vzj/
but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: i'm trying to script the 'click' through Developer tools in browser console, not manually click it. In other words, how do I trigger a click programmatically on this box?

Comment: but what are you talking about? the click is an event not an activation!

Comment: the click event is making the input box become activated and show an Autocomplete drop down.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you should be able to do it by dispatching an event:

```
var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
    "view": window,
    "bubbles": true,
    "cancelable": false
});

var inputBox = document.getElementById('inputBox');

inputBox.focus();
inputBox.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

(I left the `focus` in there in case you also wanted the highlighting of the field that you'll get with `focus`ing the element.)

Comment: Hey Mike. Thanks for answering. I tried this in console for the element provided in the fiddle. It is creating the variables correctly but doesn't really simulate the click.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("inputBox").dispatchEvent(new Event("focus"));
```